# How to add utf-8 on the default export csv

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, custom, csv, export

I have used the default export csv of magento 2 in the listing.xml.
I have a problem when I have a japanese character in the export.csv file the japanese characters are broken. How can I fix it?

```
<exportButton name="export_button" />
```

This is the default export csv of magento 2 and there's no controller or model for this.
Please help.